# SWF file is not working in my website

Tags: html, css, flash

i am new to flash.
I were converted a video file to swf file using a converter. And the converted file(SWF) is working fine in my system. after uploading the file to webs server its not working.
I cant able to identify the problem. Plz help me

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="480" height="360" id="player1" align="middle"> 
    <param name="movie" value="intro.swf"/> 
    <param name="menu" value="false"/> 
    <param name="quality" value="high"/> 
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/> 
    <noscript><a href="http://www.randeepr.webs.com/home.html">Back to Home</a></noscript> 
    <embed src="intro.swf" menu="false" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="480" height="360" name="player" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/> 
</object>
```

i am testing here http://randeepr.webs.com

Comment: @Usman: excuse me , its not like that. i don't have idea about that, so i asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="intro.swf" width="480" height="360">  
<param name="movie" value="intro.swf" /> 
</object>
```

And make sure your file path is correct.

Comment: I changed , but still in the same condition.  its not working properly. i can see the 1st layer of my swf file, afterthat  its not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me. What result do you have ?

Comment: Then i think in slow connections its showing only the 1st layer, 
ie. "Hello" after dat nothng is displaying.